# How to implement associated types in Python/Mypy? Or, what to do when wanting sub-classes to have subclass arguments?

Tags: python, types, mypy, type-systems

Consider the (simplified) code, where I want `Lean*` and `Isabelle*` extend the `Base*`.

```py
class BaseProblem: ...
class BaseStep: ...

class LeanProblem(BaseProblem): ...
class LeanStep(BaseStep): ...

class IsabelleProblem(BaseProblem): ...
class IsabelleStep(BaseStep): ...

class BaseProver:
    def f(self, problem: BaseProblem, step: BaseStep): ...
class LeanProver(BaseProver):
    def f(self, problem: LeanProblem, step: LeanStep): ...
class IsabelleProver(BaseProver):
    def f(self, problem: IsabelleProblem, step: IsabelleStep): ...
```

However, the `f` function will have problem in mypy:

```
Argument 1 of "f" is incompatible with supertype "LeanProblem";
supertype defines the argument type as "BaseProblem"  [override]
```

I know it can be solved by generics, such as:

```py
TProblem = TypeVar('TProblem', bound=BaseProblem)
TStep = TypeVar('TStep', bound=BaseStep)

class BaseProver(Generic[TProblem, TStep]):
    def f(self, problem: TProblem, step: TStep): ...
class LeanProver(BaseProver[LeanProblem, LeanStep]):
    def f(self, problem: LeanProblem, step: LeanStep): ...
...
```

However, instead of only "Problem" and "Step", indeed I have more of such types (say, 10). Thus, the approach to use generic will be quite ugly IMHO.

When using Rust, I know we can have [associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html) and it can solve the problem; but I have not found an equivalent in Python.

Comment: Generic is a proper solution here, though 10 TypeVars will look a bit scary and shouldn't be exposed as public interface, if possible. Rust associated types are just a syntactic sugar, which python as dynamically-typed language with extra optional typing layer doesn't have. Things are intentionally left simple where they can be. Here it affects only aesthetic perception and not the actual behaviour. Moreover, I don't really understand how associated types could help here - you don't have a nested generic with multiple parameters, and they let you avoid variables for trait declaration.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Hi thanks for the reply, then I may just use the generic solution. It is internal project and will not be a public interface